# Can't recover space on MacOS disk

Tags: macos, ubuntu, hard-drive, mac, partitioning

A year or so ago I partitioned my stock 2011 MacBook Air with a 30Gb (I think) partition for Ubuntu.
For a while I dual booted, all was good until eventually I purchased a dedicated Ubuntu machine and decided to return that space to my Mac.

I can't.

I killed the Ubuntu partition with Gparted, but couldn't find a way to extend the Mac partition.

Using Disk Utility I get the following problem

[image]

I've tried the suggested answers here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139157/restore-macintosh-hd-to-its-original-partition-configuration

But if I run `diskutil cs list` I get told I have no Core Storage volumes.

Any ideas folks?

Edit: I really don't care if I have to do a full machine restore.  However, I have no time machine backup.

Comment: sounds like a corrupted partition table - best thing to do would be to backup the machine (if you are still able to boot into the main Mac OS), and do a full system restore using Internet Recovery (CMD + Option + R). This will reinstall the OS your machine came with and should re-adjust the volume. Once re-installed, transfer data back

Comment: `diskutil cs list` will find no core storage because you *have* no core storage, just a standard volume. `diskutil list` will show you your volumes. Try Booting to Internet Recovery Cmd/Opt/R & run Disk Repair from there. Then, whilst you're not booted from the drive you're trying to modify, you ought to be able to resize [you might need to kill the unlabelled d0s3 first. ]

Comment: @Tetsujin - I can't seem to kill d0s3 from within Internet Recovery, and I get the a different error about file systems, but the same result when I try to extend the main partition.

Comment: @Mike - When I tried to re-install it gave me the option of installing to the reduced size disk.  I didn't proceed as wasn't sure there was a point...

Comment: @JohnRed what happens if you boot into Single User (cmd + s) at startup and run disk repair. You receive any warnings or repairs?

Comment: @Mike Cmd-S boots me into a shell.  Google tells me disk repair on the cli is diskutil repairvolume /   But, my shell doesn't recognise the diskutil command

Answer (score 0):

your fatal error was to modify the partition with Gparted. Shoulda done that with DIsk Utility (click on that partition, and click the "-" at bottom of screen, then modified the Mac partition)....

considering the partition size and HDD size, I'd VERY MUCH recommend investing in a USB drive or thunderbolt drive, doing a timemachine backup, then partition the drive again and then reinstalling the OS and doing a recovery from timemachine to it.